# How to determine if one is disqualified for ruling on bedika cloths

Tags: niddah, color

Let's say a person is minorly colorblind, as they failed one or more of the [Isihara Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishihara_test). How can they determine if they are disqualified for *mareh*'s, examining bedika cloths? If they can see red and they see brown, but when they examine cloths it's hard for them to distinguish between red and brown stains, how can they clarify if it's due to a lack of experience, or due to their colorblindness? Is there an objective way to determine this? I asked a *posek* and he wasn't sure (unless the person literally can't see red, which we're not discussing).

Comment: Not an answer, but to comment: I would assume that since this is generally learned through shimush, the Rabbi training the student should be able to make a determination as to whether the student has the ability to discern colours and rule properly in cases.